# Publish a WCF RESTful web service with Node JS

Tags: wcf, node.js, rest

Is it possible to publish a WCF RESTful web service with Node JS? If yes then please point me to tutorial/article on this topic.
I came to know about wcf.js library but I think it only supports SOAP services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wcf.js` is a library that allows node code to *call* WCF services. WCF is a framework for managed code, so you can't really use node.js to *build* WCF services (you can use something like [edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge) to call, from node.js, a DLL in C# that serves a WCF service, but the whole code would be in .NET anyway). There are many frameworks to build RESTful services with node.js, such as the ones you can find at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099389, and WCF isn't one of them.